How can I customize Approval Requests in Odoo 17?
In Odoo 17 I want to create a heavily customized Approvals process as the default options are not enough for what I need.
This can be done by extending the ApprovalCategory and ApprovalRequest classes:
e.g. of ApprovalRequest:
class ApprovalRequest(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'approval.request'

    has_field_1 = fields.Selection(related="category_id.has_field_1")
    field_1 = fields.Char(string="Field1")

However I'm not sure if this is the appropriate way to do this because it seems to bloat the class and views with fields I'm planning to only use for a specific Approval process, i.e. they won't be needed for other requests/categories.
So in essence I would like to have a custom Category with its own fields, and be able to create an Approval Request for it from Approvals, and then customize the Approve / Reject process.
Apologies if this isn't 100% clear. Feel free to request more information.
